Wordpress Subfolder link to page
I want to make my site multi-page capable. But my host only allows multidomains on subfolders.
How is it possible to create a link from URL/subfolder to a specific WordPress page?
Example: User enters https://myurl/mysubfolder in the browser and is redirected to the page https://mywordpress/mywordpresspage
Is there a possibility that a redirection can be created via htaccess - that htaccess listens from which URL the request comes and redirects to the wordpress page
